# counter_cache is stale in after_create hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache, after-create

I rely on a counter cache value in an after_create hook of my model. However, my hook is called *before* the counter cache gets updated, thus breaking a computation.

Is there any way to force a counter cache "flush" so that I always see an up-to-date value in after_create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `after_create :callback` statement is after the `has_many/belongs_to` definition.

If it doesn't work, you can create your own counter cache (it's nothing more than a call to increment/decrement, see [add_counter_cache_callbacks](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1429)) and ensure it's called before your code.

Comment: by the way, I could work around it by moving the callback to after_save, and returning unless self.id_changed? (making it equivalent to an after_create hook, just that's it's called later down the chain).